# XPS-Viewer cannot rotate, is there an alternate program that can?

Tags: windows, rotate

When I use [XPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification)-Viewer to test printing features of an application I noticed that the XPS-Viewer has no rotate function. Is there an alternative program that has this functionality? I am aware that rotating PDFs is an alternative solution.

Comment: OS: Windows. Features: Display and rotate XPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Wikipedia page for XPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification) you will see it has a section on viewers. Checking that list I found it mentions **[muPDF](https://mupdf.com/)** – a program I use on Linux and Android, and which is also available for Windows (and iOS). It can deal with XPS (and PDF, EPUB, CBZ) files, and is also capable of rotation. *muPDF* has a [gui](/questions/tagged/gui), but can also be used via [cli](/questions/tagged/cli). It's available for free and even open-source (AGPLv3).

Also see [other posts about muPDF on SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=mupdf).